# Querying if a user has a log matching the most recent version of a document using MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am trying to implement a version control system (SOPs) where those documents are revised regularly and track whether users have read the most recent version of an SOP.

I can list all SOPs where the user has read the most current version, but I can't list all the SOPs that they are out of date on e.g. for notifications that they need to read them.

The SOP table may contain multiples e.g.

```
SOP Index   SOP Code    SOP Version
1             AAA               1
2             AAA               2
3             AAA               3
4             BBB               1
5             CCC               1
6             CCC               2
```

The SOP log looks like this:

```
SOP Index    User ID     SOP Version
    1           1            1
    2           1            2
    4           1            1
```

So this shows user 1 has read the latest version of BBB, but has only read v2 of AAA although v3 is available.

I have managed to run a query that displays only the most recent SOP based on its code, e.g. from above 3, AAA, 3 |  4, BBB, 1 | 6, CCC, 2 but I am struggling to work out how to compare this to a separate table which logs the SOP index, user and version number and determine if they have read the most recent version or not.

This selects the most recent SOP:

```
SELECT a.sop_group, a.sop_code, a.sop_version, a.sop_title, a.sop_issued, 
c.log_sop_version
FROM data_sops a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sop_code, MAX(sop_version) sop_version, sop_index
    FROM data_sops
    GROUP BY sop_code) b ON a.sop_code = b.sop_code AND a.sop_version = b.sop_version
```

I've managed to extend this to select the SOPs that are the latest version the user has read with:

```
SELECT a.sop_group, a.sop_code, a.sop_version, a.sop_title, a.sop_issued, c.log_sop_version
    FROM data_sops a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT sop_code, MAX(sop_version) sop_version, sop_index
        FROM data_sops
    GROUP BY sop_code) b ON a.sop_code = b.sop_code AND a.sop_version = b.sop_version
    LEFT JOIN log_sops c ON a.sop_index = c.log_sop_sop_index
    WHERE c.log_sop_user_index = '$userid' AND c.log_sop_version = a.sop_version
```

I thought the line `WHERE c.log_sop_user_index = '$userid' AND c.log_sop_version = a.sop_version` could change operator from = to <> to give the opposite effect, but it doesn't seem to be that simple and 3 tables worth of joins in, I'm struggling to figure it out!

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x or 8.x? In 8.x the query is much simpler.

Comment: [Within-group quotas (Top N per group)](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#104)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like this to figure out which version your user has not read yet.

```
select data_sops.sop_index,data_sops.sop_code,data_sops.sop_version
from data_sops 
join (SELECT sop_code, MAX(sop_version) sop_version 
          FROM data_sops GROUP BY sop_code) a 
on data_sops.sop_code = a.sop_code 
and data_sops.sop_version = a.sop_version 
where not exists 
    (select log_sop_sop_index from log_sops 
     where data_sops.sop_index = log_sop_sop_index 
     and log_sop_user_index = '$userid')
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you